# Check words from a list in column of dataframe and print the words in another created column of the same dataframe [Python]

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list of keywords and I wish to write a Python program that can iterate each word in the list and check if the words from the list exist in each row of a column of data frame and print those words in another column of the same data frame.

e.g.

```
keywords = ['registration', 'al', 'branch']
df = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['wonderful registration process', 'i hate this branch', 'this branch has a great registration process','I don't like this place']})
```

I want to check the matched words in the list with each row of the message in the data frame and print the matched words in another created column named "keywords" of the data frame.
So the output of the above code should be

```
df    
    message
0   wonderful registration process
1   i hate this branch
2   this branch has a great registration process
3   I don't like this place

df    
    message                                               keywords
0   wonderful registration process                        registration
1   i hate this branch                                    branch
2   this branch has a great registration process          registration, branch
3   I don't like this place                               none
```

It will be great if anyone could guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your solution working like a charm.

```
import pandas as pd
keywords = ['registration', 'al', 'branch'] 
df = pd.DataFrame({'message': ["wonderful registration process", "i hate this branch", "this branch has a great registration process","I don't like this place"]})
# first of all when you have word like don't try to use ("") not ('') when defining string

#(keyword if (keyword in element)
def operation(element):
 res=",".join([(keyword) for keyword in keywords if (keyword in element)]) 
 if res=="":
  return "none" #handling no keyword situation
 else:
  return res   

df.insert(1, "keywords", list(map(operation,list(df.to_dict()['message'].values()))), True)#insert of new array
print(df)
```

[image: proof]
**Happy codding, any question you can text me on stackoverflow .**